# Missing header in Acknowledgement part

Tags: sectioning, header-footer

I have set up the acknowledgement part as follows:

```
\section*{Acknowledgements}
Thanks Mum.
```

But then, the header is missing, except the line at the top is appeared. As I want to make it standardized with the rest of the part of my document, I need to, by any means, include the header. When I search in the latex code or setting, there is no such like `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` is used. I used a template found somewhere actually, and my question is how to add such a header.

**EDIT:**

I found, perhaps, the part that configures the header. Nevertheless, I don't know how to customize it in order for it to affect on the newly added acknowledgement part as well. The part is as below(options.tex):

```
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
%\automark[chapter]{section}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ohead{\pagemark}
\ihead{\headmark}

\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}

\clubpenalty = 10000
\widowpenalty = 10000
\displaywidowpenalty = 10000
```

In main latex code:

```
\documentclass[%
12pt,
oneside,
halfparskip+,           
headsepline,            
titlepage,          
liststotoc,         
pointlessnumbers,   
bibtotoc
]
{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pseudocode}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{abstract}
\input{options.tex}

\setlength{\headheight}{1.5\baselineskip} 

\listfiles

\newcommand{\emphprolog}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

\newcommand{\TODO}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\texttt{TODO: #1}}\\} 
\newcommand{\QUESTION}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\texttt{Question: #1}}\\} 

\newcommand{\DONE}[1]{} 

\renewcommand{\emph}[1]{\textit{#1}}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{8}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{8}

\ifpdfoutput{
    \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpg,.png}
    \newcommand{\imgscale}{0.7}
} {
    \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
    \newcommand{\imgscale}{0.2}
}

\input{prefix/titlepage.tex}
\input{prefix/abstract}
\input{prefix/acknowledgements}
\pagenumbering{roman}

%\maintoc                       
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoftables                   
%\lstlistoflistings
\newpage
\listoffigures  
\clearpage      
\input{appendix/apprev}
\clearpage  
\pagenumbering{arabic}


\input{chapter/introduction}
\input{chapter/stateoftheart}
\input{chapter/approach}
\input{chapter/results}
\input{appendix/appendix}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try to make your example code complete (i.e. with `\begin{document}`, some section, your Acknowledgement and `\end{document}` so we can find out what exactly is going on.

Comment: You clearly have a lot of information hidden in other files. Try to make it [**minimal (non)-working) example**](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), I mean: remove everything that can be removed so that the resulting ONE `.tex` file can be translated by `latex` without need of other your files and the error still appears. Maybe you will find what causes the problem yourself when you make the example as simple as possible.

Comment: If you use `\addsec{}` instead of `\section*{}`, the header should appear. check the `scrguide` for details about what `\addsec` does

Comment: @Martin H: Thanks for your suggestion. It still doesn't appear after trying using `\addsec{}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're typesetting the "Acknowledgements" as an unnumbered *\section*, although `scrreprt`s highest-level sectioning command is *\chapter*. Also, `scrreprt` by default uses `oneside`, and `\addsec` (`KOMA-Scripts` alternative to `\section*`), doesn't update the header in `oneside` mode (although `\addchap`, the alternative to `\chapter*`, would). Solution: Manually update the header by using `\markright{Acknowledgements}`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ohead{\pagemark}
\ihead{\headmark}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\addsec{Acknowledgements}
\markright{Acknowledgements}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution is really handy and great..Thanks a lot for the fix!